# Обновление теней в three.js

Tags: three.js

При установке флага `shadowMap.autoUpdate = false;` в приложений блокируется обновления теней. Есть-ли варианты блокировать это обновление выборочно, не для всех объектов?

Answer (score 1):

У всех загружаемых объектов есть свойство **castShadow** (отбрасывание) и **receiveShadow** (получение). Если вам нужно отключить тень у выбранных - установите значение false для нужных свойств в этих объектах. Кроме того если объект состоит из нескольких Mesh, то можно отключить тень и внутри объекта у отдельных его частей.